# Website slide or whatever it's called

Tags: jquery, css

I need a simple horizontal slide for a website that functions like I've poorly drawn on the image:enter image description here
[image]

[image]

So, when you press the little arrow the page doesn't load up, but simply changes it's on screen position...

Just give me some page examples, or put my question right (because I have no idea how such sliding is called)

Comment: There are lots of plugins available: http://bit.ly/15jBsRT if you are trying to build one yourself please provide the code you have tried so far.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/ Try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly done with jQuery and CSS positioning.

CSS:

```
.rightslide {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 90%;
}
```

And to slide it in:

```
$('.rightslide').animate({left: "10%"});
```

Comment: thanks for the response! what can be wrong with my code, that the div refuses to move?

CSS:

div.rightslide {
 position: fixed;
 left: 94%;
 width: 1460px;
 height: 790px;
}

JS:

$('.scroll_button').click(function() {
      $('.right_slide').animate({right: "10%"});
    });

Comment: I dunno.  That looks right.  Do you have jQuery on your page?  Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Then you need to include jQuery.

Comment: that's weird, because on my previous website I've delt with a lot of jQuery, and copied the jquery.js from that folder to the new one. and, ofcourse, included it in the <script> tags

Comment: Your JavaScript also has to be after the jQuery code.

Comment: I believe everythig's in place:
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

main.js:
$('.scroll_button').click(function() {
    $('.rightslide').animate({"right": "10%"});
});

Sorry if I'm troubling you, I haven't been coding for a long time, it's hard to get back to it and maybe I don't see an obvious flaw.

Comment: Switch the main and jQuery tags.  jQuery THEN main.js

Comment: okay, done with the console error, but still doesn't move. maybe CSS is the reason?

div.container {
 width: 2960px;
 height: 710px;
}

div.leftslide {
 float: left;
 width: 1500px;
 height: 790px;
}

div.rightslide {
 position: fixed;
 left: 94%; (because I needed more than 90%)
 width: 1460px;
 height: 790px;
}

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at JQuery Mobile panels:

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/panels/

Examples are on the page itself.